# Django: Different test case structure

Tags: django, django-testing

**Background**

I have a Django *project* which will likely be deployed as several instances. The project contains numerous *apps* like the following schema:

```
myproject
|-- myapp_a
|   |-- models.py
|   ...
`-- myapp_b
|   |-- models.py
|   ...
...
```

I currently have placed a `test.py` for each of these apps within the apps directory, testing numerous features with a certain set of data (fixtures and other necessary files).

On the other hand I also have what I call the *autotest instance*, a testing deployment of my *project* where I use the above *apps* as `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
autotest
|-- conf
|   `-- someconf.conf
|-- data
|   |-- dataset1.dat
|   |-- dataset2.dat
|   |-- ...
|   `-- mydb.sqlite
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
`-- urls.py
```

My problem now is, that the testing code is supplied by my *project* but the testing data is within my *autotest instance*, but the code is course tied to the data.

I'd like to move the single `test.py` files from the *app* directories to a subfolder of the *autotest instance* like so:

```
autotest
...
|-- tests
|   |-- myapp_a
|   |   `-- test.py
|   |-- myapp_b
|   |   `-- test.py
... ...
```

but still want to invoke the testing with `python manage.py test myapp_a myapp_b ...`. How could I achieve this?